# What Vedanta philosophy is followed in Utkaliya Vaishnava of Mahapurusha Achyutananda of Odisha?

Tags: vishnu, vedanta, vaishnavism, bhakti, jnana

[Achyutananda (and the other four saints)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achyutananda#Utkaliya_Vaishnavism) believed in a concept of God (Vishnu) as Shunya (emptiness, void, zero) called Shunya Purusha and/or Shunya Brahman. This shunya signifies a transcendental principle that eludes the conceptual nexus applied to human thinking as described in the Upanishads.

**Philosophical Ideology of Achyutananda**

*Sunya Purusha*

> nāhi tāhāra rūpa varṇa, adṛsha avarṇa tā cinha. tāhāku brahmā boli
> kahi, śūnya brahmhati se bolāi.
>
> It has no shape, no colour, It is invisible and without a name This
> Brahman is called Shunya Brahman.

Achyutanada's culminating work is called the Shunya Samhita where he discusses this philosophy in depth.

> śūnyara ākāra viira śūnyara vicāra, śūnye thāi dekha vīra e
> sacarācara. dekha e sacarācara śūnyare prakāsha, śūnyu ude hoicanti
> śūnyare vilāse.
>
> Oh vira look at the shunya By placing yourself in shunya, And meditate
> on mahashunya, Shunya itself is the form, Ground of all discriminating
> knowledge. Look at the whole world from the pedestal of shunya; You
> will find everything manifested in the shunya, Everything arises out
> of shunya and Everything flourishes in the Shunya Brahman.

The philosophy sees Shunya as being full or whole (purna), and this view of Brahman is sometimes called the Purna Shunya (the full/complete void). The Panchasakhas project the deity Jagannatha as the embodiment of the Shunya Purusha. Achyutananda uses a classical (pre-Ramanuja) concept of Vaishnavism that uses both form, and formless aspects of god. This is seen in his statement from the Gurubhakti Gita :

> dui je deṇāre pakṣī uḍikari jāi, dui je cakṣure sehi saṃsāre khelai.
> eka je na thile kaṇā dui gale anḍha, eṇukari nirguṇa saguṇa sehi
> bheda.
>
> A bird can only fly with both wings. It can have a perfect vision with
> both the eyes. In the absence of one, it becomes one-eyed, and in the
> absence of both, it is totally blind. Thus like two eyes Nirguna [god
> perceived as formless]and Saguna [god perceived with form] are chained
> together.

*Jnana-mishra bhakti-marga*

The Panchasakhas were Vaishnavas by thought. But they differed from Chaitanya's path of devotion and preached Jnana-mishra bhakti or Devotion with mix of Wisdom. Chaitanya's path of devotion was known as Raganuga Bhakti Marga (brought to Odisha in 1509), which says all you need is love (devotion) to reach God.

The Panchasakhas believed that one needs a combination of love (bhakti) and wisdom (Jnana) to reach God. With our knowledge if we show our pure love (bhakti), we can definitely get the sunyatma (GOD). The Panchasakhas therefore promoted a Vaishnavism that involved study of scriptures, yoga, rituals, and devotion.

**What Vedanta philosophy is followed in Utkaliya Vaishnava of Mahapurusha Achyutananda of Odisha?**

Comment: Can you explain a few issues here? (1) Who is  vira, as mentioned in the verse of Sri Achyutananda? (2) Is the language Oriya? (3) Has the word **śūnyara** means only Sunya or nirAkAra/formless also?

Comment: This looks like a statement/introduction, what is your question? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) If it is self-answered question, you need to post the answer part as an answer.

Comment: I thiink you or wikipedia have misinterpreted and misunderstood the term shunya. It can mean emptiness but in the sense of emptiness od sensual perceptions. It does not mean non-existence or absence of Self-awareness.

Comment: I have edited your  question.  Please check whether you want to ask this question. @MohakkTRSahoshri

Comment: I do not know there exists another sect of Vaishnavism in Odisha.  Good to learn about it.  Now that I have edited your question in readable form, you can await someone's answer.  @MohakkTRSahoshri

Comment: @Srimannarayana K V, thank you very much! Yes this is followed in Odisha mainly. Utkala desa is an ancient region which is today's Odisha nearly. So Utkaliya Vaishnava may mean Vaishnavism of Odisha. I got a website who sells some of their books but all are in Odia language.